# Operation is not allowed in this context Moveprevious

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, adodb, recordset

I am getting the error ADODB.Recordset error '800a0c93'

Operation is not allowed in this context on recordset3.moveprevious.

I believe this may be something to do with cursor type ? I have tried adding in

```
recordset3.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
recordset3.open FINDPART,adoCon
```

but getting the same error.

Can someone see what's wrong with my code ?

```
 set recordset3=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
recordset3.open FINDPART,adoCon,3,3

 <% do while not recordset3.eof %>

   <% if recordset3.fields("product2") = findme then
   response.write("yes")
   recordset3.movenext
   nextpart = recordset3.fields("product2")
   recordset3.moveprevious
   recordset3.moveprevious
   previouspart = recordset3.field("product")
   exit do
   end if

   recordset3.movenext
   loop%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - Cursor Type needs to be 1

```
set recordset3=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
recordset3.cursortype =  1
recordset3.open FINDPART,adoCon
```

Comment: Instead of hard-coding constant values consider using `Constant adOpenKeyset = 1` or better still [Using METADATA to Import DLL Constants](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml) direct from the ADODB Library.